# What is a quick and simple way to know if Docker containers are running on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, monitoring, aws-event-bridge

I have a few Docker containers running on EC2 instances in AWS. In the past I have had situations where the Docker containers simply exit due to errors on the docker daemon, and they never start up even though the restart policies are in place (daemon is not running so I don't expect them to get up of course).

Since I am going on holiday I want to implement a quick and easy solution that would allow me to be notified if any containers have exited unexpectedly. The only quick solution I could find was using an Amazon Event Bridge rule for running a scheduled task every X minutes and executing a Systems Manager `RunDockerAction` command (`docker ps`) on the instances, but this does not give me any output except for the fact that the command has successfully executed on the instance.

Is there any way that I can get the output of such an Event Bridge task to send the results over an SNS topic if things go wrong?

Comment: Why not use ECS to run your containers? It simplifies a lot of things you ask about.

Comment: @Marcin Yes I will move the workload soon but this is what I have at the moment unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are running Linux on your AWS EC2 instance, then one solution is to use e-mail as a notification system. In that case, I would suggest the following:

- On the AWS EC2 instance, create a Bash script that runs `docker ps -a` and combine that with a `grep` statement to filter on the docker container IDs that you want to monitor.
- In the same Bash script, using `echo` and `mail`, you can e-mail yourself with statistics seen in the previous step. For example"

  ```
  echo "${container} is not running" | mail -s "Alert! Docker container ${container} is not running!" "first.last@domain.com"
  ```

(The above relies on `$container` to be set appropriately. Use `grep` to filter out data of interest.)

- Create a system crontab job (`etc/crontab`) and schedule the Bash script to run at your wanted interval.

This is only one possible solution, one that I use myself for quick checks at times.